# Компиляция Less в css в Brackets и VSCode

Tags: css, компиляция, visual-studio-code, less, brackets

Я только начинаю работать с препроцессором Less.
  Но компилировать его через Koola не хочется. Решил попробовать его компилировать на лету в редакторе Brackets. Но почему то у меня Brackets не находит расширение Less AutoCompile. Хотя я скачивал последнюю версию с официального сайта. Если можете, подскажите версию Brackets которая находит это расширение. Или такое же расширение для VS Code.

Comment: в vscode есть эта опция - `live sass compiler`

Comment: Ещё можно в head вставить эти 2 строки: 
        <link href='style.less'  type='text/css'  rel='stylesheet/less'>
        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.3.1/less.min.js'></script>

Comment: Максим но это компиляция sass файлов в css а мне нужно для less файлов

Comment: Владислав если я вставлю эти строки, будет ли у меня компилироваться less файл в css.

Comment: Maxim большое спасибо вам за ответ. Но я нашёл ещё лучшее расширение Easy Less.  При установленном расширении нужно создать файл less сохранить его и все изменения перенесутся в файл css. Придётся отвыкать от Brackets но ничего не поделаешь. Буду переучиваться :-)    С  уважением  Сергей

Comment: Да и как вас отблагодарить :-)